# Your PHP Version Will Be Unsupported in Joomla! 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, update, joomla-3.7, php7

I am using **PHP Version 7.0.12** and **Joomla Version 3.7.3**.

And I am facing this message "*Your PHP Version Will Be Unsupported in Joomla! 3.3*"
[image]

As per Joomla 3.3 System requirement:

> Starting with Joomla! 3.3, the minimum required PHP version is being
>   raised to PHP 5.3.10 or later!

but I already using later PHP version 7.0.12, why I am still getting this message? is any other thing I have to enable? or anything I missed? please suggest me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its a bug that will be fixed in the next release - nothing to worry about

Comment: A very warm welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange Mr. Teeman!

Comment: @Brian Teeman Thanks, looking forward to new updates :)